# When JQuery UI Autocomplete with Categories, how do I custom format the different categories?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When using JQueryUI Autocomplete with Categories, how do I custom format the different categories?

JQueryUI creates a ul that appends to after a `#menu-container <div>`.
The script below simply populates that ul with line items that are sorted by category.
What I want to do is to add a class to that category so that I can format it with individual css.

This is the html generated:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete">
<li class="ui-autocomplete-category">Activities</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andhhx10</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andk K12</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andttop C13</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andttop C11</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">anders andersson</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andreas andersson</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andreas johnson</a></li>
<li class="ui-autocomplete-category">Vendors</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">anders</a></li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">andreas</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery-ui used to generate the category listed autocomplete:

```
<script>
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
   var self = this,
    currentCategory = "";
   $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
     ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
     currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    self._renderItem( ul, item );
   });
  }
 });
</script>
<script>
var data = [
            
            { label: "andhhx10", category: "Activities" },
            { label: "andk K12", category: "Activities" },
            { label: "andttop C13", category: "Activities" }, 
            { label: "andttop C11", category: "Activities" }, 
            { label: "anders andersson", category: "Activities" },
            { label: "andreas andersson", category: "Activities" },
            { label: "andreas johnson", category: "Activities" },
            { label: "anders", category: "Vendors" },
            { label: "andreas", category: "Vendors" },
            { label: "antal", category: "Vendors" },
];
        
$( "#UserActivity" ).catcomplete({
    source: data,
    appendTo: '#menu-container',
});

</script>
```

Update, I've added the following line of code, but the class isn't appending to the line item.

```
$('#menu-container ul li:contains(Vendors)').addClass('ui-auto-vendors');
```

Update2:  JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/changhaobyu/RhHpd/

Update3:  My next problem is that I'm not attaching an event handler.  The JQuery needs to fire after the autocomplete list has populated the ul with items.  I'll Google this first and if I don't find anything I'll ask here.

Comment: Provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example.

Comment: Updated with the base case and my selector.  I'm not worried about the autocomplete rendering, it does that just fine.  I'm just trying to add a class ".ui-auto-vendors" into that particular item where inside of the line item it says "Vendors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/RhHpd/5/) works, you just needed to add `jQuery script`. Here are a couple ways of finding the `li`'s text using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-category').filter(':contains(Vendors)').addClass('ui-auto-vendors');
```

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/RhHpd/3/

---

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-category').filter(function() { 
    return $.text([this]) == 'Vendors'; 
}).addClass('ui-auto-vendors');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/RhHpd/4/